# way to specify class's type of an object in PHP

Tags: php, types, oop

Is there a way to specify an object's attribute's type in PHP ?
for example, I'd have something like :

```
class foo{
 public bar $megacool;//this is a 'bar' object
 public bar2 $megasupercool;//this is a 'bar2' object
}


class bar{...}
class bar2{...}
```

If not, do you know if it will be possible in one of PHP's future version, one day ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to the TypeHinting already mentioned, you can document the property, e.g.

```
class FileFinder
{
    /**
     * The Query to run against the FileSystem
     * @var \FileFinder\FileQuery;
     */
    protected $_query;

    /**
     * Contains the result of the FileQuery
     * @var Array
     */
    protected $_result;

 // ... more code
```

The [`@var annotation`](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/) would help some IDEs in providing Code Assistance.

Comment: Nice alternative, perfect for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is called Type Hinting and is partly available since PHP 5 / 5.1 in function declarations, but not the way you want to use it in a class definition.

This works:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
   public function test(OtherClass $otherclass) {
        echo $otherclass->var;
    }
```

but this doesn't:

```
class MyClass
  {
    public OtherClass $otherclass;
```

I don't think this is planned for the future, at least I'm not aware of it being planned for PHP 6.

you could, however, enforce your own type checking rules using [getter and setter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) in your object. It's not going to be as elegeant as `OtherClass $otherclass`, though.

[PHP Manual on Type Hinting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

Comment: It should be noted that TypeHinting is not available (yet) for Scalar Types.

Comment: @Gordon: That's right. But of course you could just check for a specific type in an short if-condition within the method. And if it is not satisfied, by the given parameter you throw an exception.

Comment: @faileN yes, something like [is_scalar()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.is-scalar.php) or any of the specific is_* functions.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can use [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) for function parameters, but you can not declare the type of a variable or class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can have other class objects in your current class, but you must make it in __contractor (or somewhere else) before use.

```
class Foo {
  private Bar $f1;
  public Bar2 $f2;
  public function __construct() {
    $f1 = new Bar();
    $f2 = new Bar2();
}}

class Bar1 {...}
class Bar2 {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the object-type, while injecting the object into the var via type-hint in the parameter of a setter-method. Like this:

```
class foo
{
    public bar $megacol;
    public bar2 $megasupercol;

    function setMegacol(bar $megacol) // Here you make sure, that this must be an object of type "bar"
    {
        $this->megacol = $megacol;
    }

    function setMegacol(bar2 $megasupercol) // Here you make sure, that this must be an object of type "bar2"
    {
        $this->megasupercol = $megasupercol;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to overload a method that way. Nice.